# Porting existing SQL Django Data to App Engine using nonrel

Tags: django, django-nonrel

I have an existing Django project, complete with Data on an SQL DB. I am using Django nonrel. I have completed all the process including porting the app and its template to app engine, however I have no idea how to port the My-SQL Data to App Engine. Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to export your SQL Database to JSON and then import it with [`manage.py loaddata`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-loaddata).